# embed a razor literal value inside an HTML attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.NET MVC Razor Engine for the first time and trying to achieve the following but it does not solve.
The variable "j" is integer and it increments for each loop.
I want the following result

```
<tr class="gridrow1">....
<tr class="gridrow2">....
<tr class="gridrow3">....
```

...

```
<tr class="gridrow100">
```

I am unable to figure out how to use razor here, I tried all the following but nothing worked.

```
<tr class="gridrow"@j>
<tr class="gridrow'@j'">
<tr class="gridrow'@Html.Raw(j)'">
<tr class="gridrow"@Html.Raw(j)>
```

please help.

Comment: You may be thinking too hard about it. Have you tried `<tr class="gridrow@j">` (note the location and number of quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        string className = "gridRow_" + @i.ToString();
        <tr class="@className">
            <td>
                @i
            </td>
        </tr>
    }</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by using a String.Concat statement

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {                
            <tr class="@String.Concat("gridrow",i.ToString())" ><td>Hello</td></tr>
        }
```

Comment: Because, in general, string concatenation is so fast and memory-efficient?  ;-) /sarcasm...

Comment: Well, use any efficient mechanism here, its C# code behind allowed here :)